# How to programmatically change the text of an anchor tag in a JSP

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I would like to be able to change the text of an anchor tag based on the value of the status field.
On pageload the student-status is set by a ajax request. After which I would like to check that status and see if it is active, then the hyperlink should say "DeActivate" otherwise Activate.
Below I am doing the test by hardcoding the status field to Active. I would like to actually use the value that is in the  with the id =student-status.
Is there a way to set the status variable similar to $("#student-status).text()
Example here below:

```
<tr>
  <td>Status</td>
  <td id="student-status"></td>
   <c:set var ="status" scope="session" value="Active" /> <!-- want to get value from td -->
   <c:choose>
    <c:when test = "$(status == 'Active')">
     <td class="new-student-status"><a id="activate-deactivate-student" href="#">DeActivate</a></td>
</c:when>
<c:when test = "$(status== 'Inactive')">
<td class="new-student-status"><a id="activate-deactivate-student" href="#">Activate</a></td>
</c:when>
</c:choose>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one line:

```
<td class="new-student-status">
   <a id="activate-deactivate-student" href="#">
      <c:out value="$(status == 'Active'?'DeActivate':'Activate')"/>
   </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, I dont know what the status is- it is displayed in the **<td id="student-status"></td>** field. Hence, I want to do something like **var status = $('#student-status').text()**. Since this is in a .jsp, I dont think I can do it.

Comment: I was able to solve this problem by changing the text of the anchor tag and the same time the Ajax request was calculating the status field.Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#student-status').html(desiredText)` will set the inner text of the `#student-status` element to the value of the `desiredText` variable.

Comment: I want to be able to read what $('#student-status).text() is.